# Storing iteration values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
  file_open=open("/python32/doc1.txt","r")
  file=a1.read().lower()
  for line in file:
       line_word=line.split()
```

This works fine. But if I print `line_word` it would be printed continuously.
I like to store in some variable, so that I may print a line of my choice and manipulate them at my choice.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Generally I append to a list and do the necessary stuff, but for bigger files it is really problematic.

If anyone can kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: If you have to store the data, whether it be in a list or elsewhere, it's going to be problematic with bigger files. Can you store a subset of the data instead?

Comment: You read in the file in one go, so you are iterating over a string; character by single character.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `.read()` to iterate over the lines of a file.

```
with open("/python32/doc1.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line_word = line.lower().split()
```

Comment: Seems a nice one Marco. But well I have to make nerve too to write big codes.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
file_open=open("/python32/doc1.txt","r")
file=a1.read().lower()
line_word = []
for line in file.splitlines():
    line_word.append(line.split())
```